# Android rxjava change list object inside other list

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I get an API response and i create a `List<Logs>`. This list includes another list `List<Debits>`. What i want to do is get each `Debits` object and change its type variable, and then return the changed `List<Logs>`. I have the code below

```
val s = accountRepository.Logs
            .filter { result -> result.isSuccessful }
            .map { result -> result.result.creditLog }
            .flatMap { Logs -> Observable.from(Logs)
                    .map { Log ->
                        copyLog(Log, Observable.from(Log.debits)
                                .map { debit -> copyDebit(debit, "pc") }
                                .toList().toBlocking().single()) }
                    .toList()
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ Logs ->

            },{RxErrorHandler()})
```

I have managed to iterate through `List<Logs>` and then through `List<Debits>`, tried using `.toList()` but could not get the desired result. I there a guideline or an example on how to do this?

Comment: can you show us the code you used to accomplish what you want to do without success?

Comment: @LeandroOcampo just updated my question

Comment: It's unclear what you try to achieve here. How would you do it with traditional for-loops outside RxJava? for each log in logs, for each debit in log.debits do something?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using RxJava along with Kotlin, why not making the most of it?

I will remove some observables, which I think you do not need them:

```
          val s = accountRepository.Logs
                        .filter { result -> result.isSuccessful }
                        .map { result -> 
                          result.result.creditLog.foreach{ 
                             log ->
                              log.debits.foreach{ debit -> debit.type = “pc” }
                          }
                        return result.creditLog  
                 }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe({ Logs ->

                        },{RxErrorHandler()})
```

I haven't tested the code but I would say you need minor fixes / changes